# Cannot build Boost with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: boost

I downloaded Boost 1.63.0 and tried building it with my newly installed Visual Studio 2017 but there is no way it works! It compiles with the Visual Studio 2015 compiler instead.

Let me be more clear. I have both Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and Visual Studio 2017 installed in my laptop. I open a command prompt with the environment set for the 2017 compiler (which is version 15.0).

Then I execute:

b2 --layout=versioned --with-chrono

but it uses version 14.0 (toolset=msvc-14.0) instead of version 15.0...

Thanks!
Juan Dent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build boost with msvc 14.1 ( VS2017 RC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464356/build-boost-with-msvc-14-1-vs2017-rc)

Comment: Boost does not currently support 2017. It's being discussed on the boost-dev list.