# How to compile the lastest Boost(Version 1.63.0)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, installation

Thanks for @Praetorian 'help, problem Was solved.

That's what I do:

1. download the beta version of boost (present beta version: 1.64)
2. Do what's told here: [How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010)

   ---

To install Boost, I have done what am I told(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/more/getting_started/ and [How to use Boost in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010).)

But "argument error" still returned after running b2

What's the mistake do I make?

//What I do

$ b2 --toolset=msvc-14.0 --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage

//Return

*** argument error

- rule maybe-rewrite-setup ( toolset : setup-script : setup-options : version : rewrite-setup ? )
- called with: ( msvc :  :  : default :  )
- missing argument setup-script

//Using

Visual Studio 2017 community

x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017

Comment: Follow the instructions here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/41464356/241631. Or download the latest beta version of Boost, that supports VS2017.

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you very much. I've download the beta version. It works.

Comment: @Praetorian, since your comment works for cyy5358, could you please add a reply with this information when you have free time, and I will recommend cyy5358 to mark it, it will help other community members who meet the same issue to easier search this useful workaround, thanks in advance :)