# boost 1.66.0 with visual studio 2017, b2 keeps using cl.exe under ARM folder

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017

I scratched my head hard but could not find someone asks the same question.
I'm building boost 1.66 with VS2017 on my machine, the command I'm using is `b2 -a -j6 toolset=msvc-14.1 link=static runtime-link=static,shared address-model=64 architecture=x86 define=BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE --with-math`.

I think it should use `cl.exe` from `Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\bin\Hostx64\x64`

However, from the log b2 gives me[image]

It looks really weird to me that it's using `cl.exe` under arm folder to compile my `address-model=64` binaries. My question is, will the binary be the same as what I expected? Could this be a bug in boost build engine, and is there a workaround to make this look right?

P.S.: I've tried editing project-config.jam to hardcode the path of desired location of compiler, but it returns me "could not locate correct compiler cl". What I referenced is: [build-boost-with-msvc-14-1-vs2017-rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464356/build-boost-with-msvc-14-1-vs2017-rc)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.66.0/

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the reference link, Hans. However, I really want to know why exactly this happened.

Comment: Somebody needs to fix that eternal bjam misery.  Greek tragedy stuff, I've seen grown man cry.  Starts with "oh, boost can do that" and the next thing you notice is that they haven't brushed their teeth for a week.  I'll volunteer you.